# Testing location in WP7 emulator

Tags: gps, location, windows-phone-7.1

So I'm using [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431782%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) but having zero luck on testing to decide whether it was working or not. The only variation from that code is that instead of changing a TextBlock, I'm setting a static GeoCoordinate object declared outside of the functions.

```
public static void PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        coord = e.Position.Location;
    }
```

Well, I change the status thing to instead of display in a text box, to display a MessageBox with OK button, and removed the button event.

In the MainPage render I have:

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (watcher == null)
        {
            watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
            watcher.MovementThreshold = 20;

            watcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(StatusChanged);
            watcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(PositionChanged);
        }
        watcher.Start();
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            string blah = "";
            blah += coord.Latitude.ToString();
            blah += "; " + coord.Longitude.ToString();
```

However, if I don't initialize coord, it errors out (understandable) but if I do = new GeoCoordinate(); it returns back NaN for all of the numeric items. I've set breakpoints inside of the event handlers which never hit (expected behavior though?)

In the emulator, I used the >> thing, set it to live and picked a few locations, set the time to switch location to 10 seconds and played it while running debug. Am I doing the debug/running the location portion of the emulator incorrectly?

update: after updating it to remove the string blah items to create a list based on the location, it appears to be working.

Comment: You don't appear to have any code to update the view when the co-ordinate changes?

Comment: The only things I've seen in the document was using the status/position changed events and in the example's case, updating TextBlock controls. I wanted to update the current location on application load so that I can get a list of things in the general area. There is code beyond it (blah was a variable used for testing), but blah comes back as "NaN; NaN" which prevents the checks going forward.

Comment: What I mean is that your `PositionChanged` method updates your `coord`, *but you never read it* except before it's had a chance to be set, nor does your code use any databinding to auto-update -- if your coord was on your ViewModel (assuming you're following the MVVM pattern, going by the property names), then your event handler that listens for position changes could also raise the PropertyChanged event for the ViewModel's version of your current `blah` variable

Comment: You were correct. Once I removed the blah code to re-generate my list of items, it appears to be working properly. Not sure of the why, but it is at least. If you don't mind, create an answer with your 2nd comment and I'll mark as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PositionChanged` method updates your coord, but you never read it except before it's had a chance to be set, nor does your code use any databinding to auto-update -- if your coord was on your ViewModel (assuming you're following the MVVM pattern, going by the property names), then your event handler that listens for position changes could also raise the PropertyChanged event for the ViewModel's version of your current `blah` variable